# Даны 5 чисел (тип int). Вывести вначале наименьшее, а затем наибольшее из данных чисел. С помощью массива

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм

Как это сделать с помощью массива,просто я ещё не очень хорошо знаю как применять массив
помогите пожалуйста)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a = in.nextInt();
    int b = in.nextInt();
    int c = in.nextInt();
    int d = in.nextInt();
    int x = in.nextInt();
    int min =0;
    int max= 0;

    if (a<b&&a<c&&a<d&&a<x)min =a;
    else if (b<a&&b<c&&b<d&&b<x)min =b;
    else if (c<a&&c<b&&c<d&&c<x)min =c;
    else if (d<a&&d<c&&d<b&&d<x)min =d;
    else if (x<a&&x<c&&x<d&&x<b)min =x;
    System.out.println("Наменьшее:"+ min);

    if (a>b&&a>c&&a>d&&a>x)max =a;
    else if (b>a&&b>c&&b>d&&b>x)max =b;
    else if (c>a&&c>b&&c>d&&c>x)max =c;
    else if (d>a&&d>c&&d>b&&d>x)max =d;
    else if (x>a&&x>c&&x>d&&x>b)max =x;
    System.out.println("Наибольшее:"+ max);
```

Comment: Но там тоже нет нормального ответа. Напишите кто-нибудь ответ на streams API, а? Здесь или там.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если принципиально использовать массив, то можно инициализировать массив полученными значениями, например:

```
Integer[] intArr = {a,b,c,d,x};
```

После этого применять на нем алгоритмы поиска минимального и максимального значений. Самое очевидное на мой взгляд решение будет:

```
int maxArr = intArr[0];
int minArr = intArr[0];
for(Integer value : intArr) {
    if (value > maxArr) {
        maxArr = value;
    }
    if (value < minArr) {
        minArr = value;
    }
}
```

И как советуют в комментариях, лаконичным будем вариант решения с использованием Stream API:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(a, b, c, d, x);
Integer max = list.stream().max(Integer::compareTo).get();
Integer min = list.stream().min(Integer::compareTo).get();
```