# Подсчитать количество пар соседних элементов с разными знаками в двумерном массиве

Tags: c++, c, массивы, динамические-массивы

Задание:

Подсчитать количество соседних элементов с разными знаками в двумерном массиве. Размерность массива задает пользователь. Элементы массива формируются рандомно от -50 до 50.

То есть, нужно подсчитать количество пар не только по горизонтали, но и по вертикали. Допустим дан массив 3 на 3.

-10   5  3
-20 -15 36
 15  8  -9

Элемент с индексом 0 сравниваем не только со следующим элементом, но и с элементом который стоит ниже его. -10 сравниваем с 5 и снова же -10 сравниваем с -20, и так далее проходя по всем элементам массива.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));// генерация случайных чисел

    int max_i, max_j, total = 0;

        cout << "Enter the number of rows: ";
        cin >> max_i;
        cout << "Enter the number of columns: ";
        cin >> max_j;

        cout << endl;

        // динамическое создание двумерного массива вещественных чисел
        int **pointer = new int* [max_i];
        for(int counter = 0; counter < max_i; counter++)
        {
            pointer[counter] = new int [max_j];
        }

        // заполнение массива
        for(int count_row = 0; count_row < max_i; count_row++)
        {
            for(int count_column = 0; count_column < max_j; count_column++)
            {
                pointer[count_row][count_column] = (rand()% 100 + (-50));
            }
        }

        // вывод массива
        for(int count_row = 0; count_row < max_i; count_row++)
        {
            for(int count_column = 0; count_column < max_j; count_column++)
            {
                cout << setw(4) << pointer[count_row][count_column] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        /*Вот \та часть кода работает некорректно  
        for(int i = 0; i < max_i; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; i < max_j; j++)
            {
                if((i+1) < max_i)
                {
                    if((pointer[i][j]) > 0 && (pointer[i+1][j]) < 0)**Именно вот эта строка вызывает ошибку**
                    {
                        total += 1;
                    }
                }

                if((j+1) < max_j)
                {
                    if((pointer[i][j]) > 0 && (pointer[i][j+1]) < 0)
                    {
                        total += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
      */
        cout << "Pair: " << total << endl;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Код работает до самой части подсчета пар.

Ошибка:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00065265 in arr.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation reading location 0x0043B028.

Как я понимаю, я вышел за допустимую область чтения данных в программе. Как это исправить?

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему.

Comment: @sanixНикто и не говорит, что домашнее задание должны делать все и полностью с нуля, кроме автора. Я написал код, у меня не получилось сделать рабочую программу. Я же не написал :"Ребят, вот условие, напишите мне рабочую программу", я попросил указать мне на мою ошибку в коде и помочь ее исправить. Вас никто не заставляет помогать, я лишь попросил совета и выставил мою проблему на общее обозрение.

Comment: да тут вот уже сколько вопросов  по дз: [раз](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/572779/221419) [два](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/572763/221419) [три](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/572730/221419) и еще туча.. тем более они такие простые, что ппц.. загуглить даже лень!

Comment: @sanix Я не нашел ответа на мой вопрос пользуясь гуглом, поэтому и обратился именно сюда.

Comment: @RomaSypko: Смотрите. Разбираться в вашей домашке здесь будет всем лень, примите это за факт. Но если у вас есть код, это уже гораздо лучше. Если он не работает, то постарайтесь найти **ту строку**, в которой происходит первая проблема. Для этого вам придётся воспользоваться отладчиком (умеете?), пройти программу по шагам и посмотреть, соответствуют ли значения переменных вашему представлению. Как только не будут соответствовать, тут-то и проблема. Вот с этой проблемой и приходите. А отлаживать ваш код нам тут скучно, мы это делаем каждый день на работе.

Comment: @VladD Умею. Ошибку я нашел и только что редактировал пост, но как это исправить я не имею понятия.

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации и задайте вопрос с описанием конкретных проблем.

Answer (score 2):

У вас опечатка во втором цикле (вложенном) в закомментированном коде:

```
for(int i = 0; i < max_i; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; i < max_j; j++)
```

> for(int j = 0; **i < max_j**; j++)

Там должно быть

> **j < max_j**

Будьте внимательнее :)

Comment: Это не опечатка, это копипаст)